# Does the fact that a company stated they were a non profit corporation in an NDA when they are not allow for the contract to be voided?

Tags: contract-law, non-disclosure, non-profit

In this particular NDA, the company lists its name and states "a non-profit corporation". In reality, they left off the LLC from the company name, and the company has never been designated as a "non-profit". Can this alone cause the NDA to be invalid as there is no non-profit corporation with that name? How would one go about fighting the validity of an NDA?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In general, an error in describing a party or an incomplete description, as long as it is clear what party is meant, will not invalidate a contract, such as an NDA.

Comment: Is the NDA affected by the non-profit status of the company? In other words, if claiming they were a non-profit gave them better terms, it would be different than if the non-profit status doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this alone cause the NDA to be invalid as there is no non-profit corporation with that name?

No. Contracts or agreements do not intrinsically depend on the veracity of a party's [non-]profit character. Instead, they primarily depend on the parties' common understanding or [meeting of the minds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meeting_of_the_minds).

> How would one go about fighting the validity of an NDA?

Strictly speaking, it is about *voiding the NDA rather than challenging it as *invalid*. In terms of [Restatement (Second) of Contracts](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/p/restatement-second-contracts.html) at §153, you as counterparty would need to prove that the company's representation of being a non-profit entity constituted "*a basic assumption on which [you] made the contract [and] has a material effect on the agreed exchanged of performances*" (but see also Restatement at §154).

Comment: This is not limited to statements of being [non-]profit character, is it? Generally, lying in a contract about who you are, or, even more generally, making _a_ misrepresentation does not on the spot void the contract, does it?

Comment: @Greendrake "*This is not limited to statements of being [non-]profit character, is it?*" No. The principle applies to misrepresentations which are *material* to the counterparty's decision-making on with whom to enter a contract.